# Replace haproxy by ingress in AKS

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I'am new in Azure Kubernetes.

I'm implementing a AKS and  I want to use ingress in order to be redirected to `app-front POD` when i tape `https://front.domain.com`
and be redirect to `grafana POD` when i tape `https://grafana.domain.com` in the brosser.

I Ask if it's possible to do that without use haproxy for example.

I manage DNS sub-domain in OVH.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can install an Ingress controller like [NGINX Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/). If you need certificate management (via Let's Encrypt) also install [cert-manager](https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/kubernetes/).

Using Helm this can be done with:

```sh
helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
helm repo update
helm install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx
```

and

```sh
helm repo add jetstack https://charts.jetstack.io
helm repo update
helm install cert-manager jetstack/cert-manager --namespace cert-manager --create-namespace
```

Comment: and for the routing using subdomain ?

Comment: Set the wildcard DNS to the IP of the ingress-nginx - then you can expose any subdomain via ingress objects

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) with a chosen [Ingress Controller(s)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/). Ingress Controller is needed as:

> In order for the Ingress resource to work, the cluster must have an
> ingress controller running.
>
> Unlike other types of controllers which run as part of the
> `kube-controller-manager` binary, Ingress controllers are not started
> automatically with a cluster. Use this page to choose the ingress
> controller implementation that best fits your cluster.

[Create an ingress controller in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic) will show you a step by step guide describing an example of how it could be implemented.

As for the routing, the [Create an ingress route](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic#create-an-ingress-route) shows how it works:

> To route traffic to each application, create a Kubernetes ingress
> resource. The ingress resource configures the rules that route traffic
> to one of the two applications.

Based on your question, if your service is only reachable via https you need to add the following [annotation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#backend-protocol) to your ingress yaml:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
```